# Mute assets requests in development log (config.assets.quiet = true doesn't work)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Has anyone managed to mute assets logging in Rails 6. config.assets.quiet = true does't work, I tried all options I could find

Comment: What logger are you using? You should use this:
`config.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)`

Comment: I did not specify logger, don't know what's the default logger. I'm using passenger in dev